# External event on Highcharts/highstock

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm using `ng-drag-drop` and highcharts/highstocks. 
I need to drag and drop an external item into the highcharts/highstock and create a marker. Per the docs in highcharts/highstocks, you can drag and drop but it is within the chart container.

So what I did was get the event of the entire page.
On drag and drop, I retrieve where I dropped the position relative to the entire web page. My question is, how do I translate the entire page position (pageX, pageY) into highcharts/highstock coordinates (within the plot). The dragged item is dragged from a parent component and into a child component, where the chart is.

[image]

//parent component

```
OnItemDropped(e:any){
  //X and Y coordinates of the entire webpage when item is dropped
  const add = { coord: { x: e.nativeEvent.pageX, y: e.nativeEvent.pageY }, name:'marker1' }
this.pinnedItems = [...this.pinnedItems, add]
}
```

so `coord.x` and `coord.y` is the entire page. but I need it to set at the page coordinates. Obviously, the position doesn't match with chart's. Is there a way where highcharts can recognize the page's XY coordinates as the chart's XY coordinates?

Alternatively, I thought about retrieving the html value of the page coord. But I cant seem to find out where that resides in the nativeElement object.

Comment: Could you please prepare a simplified online example of your app with sample data presenting this issue (codesandbox for example)? Are you using highcharts official wrapper for Angular: github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular?